# How to find the equation for the mentioned Neural network decision boundary?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmB8T.jpg

Can someone help with with this question with explanation... I am unable to understand how to derive the final equation...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework problem

Comment: It is not a homework problem i found this on a website and i am unclear with the concept....
If someone can help it would be great as i am currently learning ML and DL Concepts...
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/01/must-know-questions-deep-learning/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.